# How do i set limit query into url from views output

Tags: views

In drupal i need to output json fields. So i used [views_datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource). In my situation, i need to call same api source to multiple section, but i don't want to create multiple view only for 5 items or 10 items or all items for same content types data. So in **views_datasource** i need to use limit filter from all of views results like "http://example.com/serve/all-articles?limit=10".

Can anybody help me to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ccreate a custom module and implement [hook_views_pre_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7).

To create the module follow these steps:

In `sites/all/modules` create a new folder with the name of your module. As you are not contributing this module back to Drupal and it is specific to your project just give it the name of your project and other code tweaks can also live in there.

Let's assume you called your project `custom_project` and it is at `sites/all/modules/custom_project`.

Add a file called `custom_project.info` to it with this content:

```
name = Custom Project Module     
description = This module is for project related tweaks     
core = 7.x
```

Add a file called `custom_project.module` with this content:

```
<?php
function custom_project_views_pre_build(&$view){
  if ($view->name == "NAMEOFVIEW") {
    if (isset($view->args[0]) && is_numeric($view->args[0])) {
      $view->set_items_per_page($view->args[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Now install this module (and in future if you add any hooks then clear the cache)

You call this on a friendly url ("http://example.com/serve/all-articles/10").

If you wish to add a query parameter to the url as in "http://example.com/serve/all-articles?limit=10" then your function will need to inspect [drupal_get_query_parameters](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7) for that parameter instead of pulling it out of `$view->args[0]`.

ie.:

```
<?php
function custom_project_views_pre_build(&$view){    
  if ($view->name == "NAMEOFVIEW") {    
    $query_params = drupal_get_query_parameters();    
    if (isset($query_params['limit']) && is_numeric($query_params['limit'])) {    
      $view->set_items_per_page($query_params['limit']);    
    }    
  }    
}
```

You need to replace `NAMEOFVIEW` with your views name. You get it like this:

[image]

Note that a view has a name, but also a display id. The display id in this case is page. If you add a block it will get a block display id. So the above code will work for all displays that you add to this view, even for blocks etc. To limit it to just the page you will change the one line to this:

```
if ($view->name == "all_content_of_article" && $view->current_display == "page") {
```

Comment: Hi @J. Reynolds, Thanx  for quick reply. I m new to develop drupal module, can you please help me to setup above functions into .module file? :( sorry for this request...

Comment: OMG... :) thanx your response. Now i trying to implement your codes. I'll inform you after sometime...

Comment: Oh Man... You are genius... It's working!!! :)
Now i add **offset query** with your codes myself.

Comment: Reynonls,
If you don't mind, may can i ask a new question?

Comment: Yes just post it as a new question

Comment: Hi, @J.Reynolds, last december 14, i already asking here "http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138638/track-how-many-times-a-json-file-is-requested-from-other-websites" but i can't find any solution. Can you please help to solve my this problem? i update my question there.

Answer (score 0):

Is using another display in the same view out of the question? It would be a lot easier than a programmatic approach in my opinion?

You could then have all your base configurations on the view main display and create another display with the single override?

If you did go the custom route, you may have to deal with the more complex view caching or disable the views cache on this view.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'd disagree, it says use this method instead of dealing with the headache that could be caused using the programmatic approach.